# 500 backend error while inserting YouTube Channel Art

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Although, we'd prepared YouTube channel art upload mechanism as described on the it's official documentation page, (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelBanners/insert), from few days, we are facing following error,

```
A service error occurred: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "backendError", "message": "Backend Error" } ], "code": 500, "message": "Backend Error" } }
```

Which was perfectly working before.

```
  /**
     * This sample sets a custom banner for a user's channel by:
     *
     * 1. Uploading a banner image with "youtube.channelBanners.insert" method via resumable upload
     * 2. Getting user's channel object with "youtube.channels.list" method and "mine" parameter
     * 3. Updating channel's banner external URL with "youtube.channels.update" method
     *
     * @author Ibrahim Ulukaya
    */

    /**
     * Library Requirements
     *
     * 1. Install composer (https://getcomposer.org)
     * 2. On the command line, change to this directory (api-samples/php)
     * 3. Require the google/apiclient library
     *    $ composer require google/apiclient:~2.0
     */
    if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
      throw new \Exception('please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "' . __DIR__ .'"');
    }

    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    session_start();
    //session_destroy();
    /*
     * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
     * {{ Google Cloud Console }} <{{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}>
     * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
     * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
     * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
     */
    $OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'OUR_CLIENT_ID';
    $OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'OUR_CLIENT_SECRET';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
    $redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
        FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

    // Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
    $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    // Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
    $tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
      if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
        die('The session state did not match.');
      }

      $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
      header('Location: ' . $redirect);
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
    }

    // Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
      $htmlBody = '';
      try{

        // REPLACE with the path to your file that you want to upload for thumbnail
        $imagePath = "2560x1440-pixels-image.jpg";
        $imageSize = get_headers($imagePath, 1);

        // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
        // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
        // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
        $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
        // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
        $client->setDefer(true);

        $chan = new Google_Service_YouTube_ChannelBannerResource();

        // Create a request for the API's channelBanners.insert method to upload the banner.
        $insertRequest = $youtube->channelBanners->insert($chan);

        // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $client,
            $insertRequest,
            'image/jpeg',
            null,
            true,
            $chunkSizeBytes
        );
        //$media->setFileSize(filesize($imagePath));
        $media->setFileSize($imageSize["Content-Length"]);


        // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
        $status = false;
        $handle = fopen($imagePath, "rb");
        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
          $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
          $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
        }

        fclose($handle);

        // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
        $client->setDefer(false);

        $thumbnailUrl = $status['url'];

        // Call the API's channels.list method with mine parameter to fetch authorized user's channel.
        $listResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('brandingSettings', array(
            'mine' => 'true',
        ));

        /*echo '<pre>';
        print_r($listResponse);
        echo '</pre>';*/

        $responseChannel = $listResponse[0];
        $responseChannel['brandingSettings']['image']['bannerExternalUrl']=$thumbnailUrl;

         // Call the API's channels.update method to update branding settings of the channel.
         $updateResponse = $youtube->channels->update('brandingSettings', $responseChannel);

         $bannerMobileUrl = $updateResponse["brandingSettings"]["image"]["bannerMobileImageUrl"];

         $htmlBody .= "<h3>Thumbnail Uploaded</h3><ul>";
         $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s</li>',
             $thumbnailUrl);
         $htmlBody .= sprintf('<img src="%s">', $bannerMobileUrl);
         $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

      } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
            htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
      } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
            htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
      }

      $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } elseif ($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID == 'OUR_CLIENT_ID') {
      $htmlBody = <<<END
      <h3>Client Credentials Required</h3>
      <p>
        You need to set <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> and
        <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> before proceeding.
      <p>
    END;
    } else {
      // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
      $state = mt_rand();
      $client->setState($state);
      $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
      $htmlBody = <<<END
    <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
    <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
    END;
    }
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Banner Uploaded and Set</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?=$htmlBody?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What changed before it was working and after it stopped working? Did you make any changes at all?

Comment: Nope, nothing. We'd tested it before numerous time with expected output before developing app.

Comment: I hope you have put the right credentials for your CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET in the original source code

Comment: Yeah, OUR_CLIENT_ID and OUR_CLIENT_SECRET part of the above questions are replaced version of previously working credentials. We'd also tried with new app and credentials with no luck.

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#500_backend_error), if an unexpected error occurred while processing the request, suggested action is to use [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff).

Comment: Exponential Backoff might not be feasible on our case.